# Why is my Python app in Heroku not compiling?

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Python application on [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) for a course I'm doing. The error I'm getting has me a bit confused as I haven’t seen any responses online for something similar. Error messages are:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-apt==2.4.0 (from versions: 0.0.0, 0.7.8) 
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-apt==2.4.0

How can I to fix these?

I commented out `python-apt==2.4.0` and got different errors.

Comment: so the python script/app had no issues when you ran it in local?

Comment: [PyPI's version](https://pypi.org/project/python-apt/) of this module is no longer maintained and has been yanked (technical term). If you want its functionalities, you need to install it through linux based package repository, e.g: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-apt

Comment: yea it works fine in the command line. Ok cheers I'll give that a go!